# Vue display two objects of an array inside a v-for

Tags: json, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to display two objects of an array inside a v-for?

Like i want to display testimonials and the UI of the project have a slide group which displays two testimonials for each row.

```
            <v-slide-group>
                <v-slide-item v-for="(n, index) in testimonials" :key="'testimonial-' + index" class="m-4" style="width: 500px;">
                    <div>
                        <div class="row">

                          --- First Testimonial of row ----

                            <div class="col-12 pb-0">
                                <v-icon x-large color="#afbf3a" class="quote-open">
                                    mdi-format-quote-open
                                </v-icon>
                                <v-card class="mb-2" min-width="200" max-width="500" style="border-radius: 20px;">
                                    <v-card-text class="pl-7 pt-7 pr-3 pb-4">
                                        <p v-html="n.text" class="m-0" style="color: #b8b8b8; font-style: italic;">
                                            </p>
                                    </v-card-text>
                                    <v-card-actions class="pb-4">
                                        <div class="d-flex" style="align-items: flex-end;">
                                            <v-avatar class="ml-4 pb-4 avatar-shadow">
                                                <v-img contain :src="n.img"></v-img>
                                            </v-avatar>
                                            <p class="ml-2 font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 13px; color: #afbf3a;">
                                                {{n.name}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </v-card-actions>
                                </v-card>
                                <v-icon x-large color="#afbf3a" class="quote-close">
                                    mdi-format-quote-close
                                </v-icon>
                            </div>

                            --- Second Testimonial of row ----

                            <div class="col-12 pb-0 position-relative pt-0" style="left: 50px; bottom: 20px;">
                                <v-icon x-large color="#afbf3a" class="quote-open">
                                    mdi-format-quote-open {{ index = index + 1 }}
                                </v-icon>
                                <v-card class="mb-2" min-width="200" max-width="500" style="border-radius: 20px;">
                                    <v-card-text class="pl-7 pt-7 pr-3 pb-4">
                                        <p v-html="n.text" class="m-0" style="color: #b8b8b8; font-style: italic;">
                                            </p>
                                    </v-card-text>
                                    <v-card-actions class="pb-4">
                                        <div class="d-flex" style="align-items: flex-end;">
                                            <v-avatar class="ml-4 pb-4 avatar-shadow">
                                                <v-img contain :src="n.img"></v-img>
                                            </v-avatar>
                                            <p class="ml-2 font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 13px; color: #afbf3a;">
                                                {{n.name}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </v-card-actions>
                                </v-card>
                                <v-icon x-large color="#afbf3a" class="quote-close">
                                    mdi-format-quote-close
                                </v-icon>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </v-slide-item>
                <v-btn class="position-relative slider-btn" style="right: 10px;" small fab color="white" slot="next">
                    <v-icon small color="#afbf3a">
                        mdi-chevron-right
                    </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn class="position-relative slider-btn" style="left: 10px; z-index: 99999;" small fab color="white" slot="prev">
                    <v-icon small color="#afbf3a">
                        mdi-chevron-left
                    </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </v-slide-group>
```

Is there a way to double the index like n + 2 or something like that? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed property in order to create a new array or object. There you can use an ordinary js for loop.

But the whole reason to use v-for is to be able to skip the second testmonial with identical code as the first one.
If you need two from a larger array you can use the computed property to filter out the two you want to display.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Please mark as answer.

Comment: Not the answer i was looking for.

Comment: If you explain in more detail I can help you out.

Comment: This answer is actually correct, almost two years later and a lot of practice i actually understand now what you meant and that would probably be the best solution at the time. Thank you.